# Clarification on the notation of a paper about hybrid

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, notation, integration, density-operator

Here is a screenshot from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00544a007) by J. P. Foster and F. Weinhold. This paper focuses on a model of hybridization. It therefore considers movement of electrons in three dimensions.

The author does not define what $d1,d2,\ldots, dN$ mean. Perhaps, $1$ is actually $\mathbf x_1$, the position of the first electron.

Could anyone help clarify what the first few equations mean? This should be very easy. Apparently, this is just a matter of notation.

I don't know if this is appropriate for this site. Please tell me if I need to ask it somewhere else.

[image]

Comment: The spinless first-order reduced density matrix is the integral of $N\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_2,\dots)\Psi^*(\mathbf{r}',\mathbf{r}_2,\dots)$ with respect to the positions of electrons $2,3,\dots$. Some authors use the notation $d\mathbf{r}_i=di$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty obvious that $d1$ is shorthand for $d^3x_1$ where $x_1$ is the position. In other words he is is being lazy and means
$$
\psi(1,2,3,\ldots)\equiv \psi(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots).
$$